# To round of decimal value in ADF pipeline expression (Cannot fit unknown into the function parameter string.)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to round of the decimal value in adf pipeline expressions.
As there is no built in function in pipeline expressions.So i tried in the way first to multiply the number with 100 (as i want to limit to 2 decimal places), then split the number and then divided with 100.

multiply > 123.34231 * 100 = 12334.231

split > [12334 , 231 ]

divide first index > 12334/100 = 123.34

I used following expression to round off the value >  @string(div(float(split(string(mul(123.34231,100)),'.')[0]),100))

to multiply with 100 > **mul(123.34231,100)**
to split the number and select 0th index > **split(string(mul(123.34231,100)),'.')[0]**
to divide with 100 > **div(float(split(string(mul(123.34231,100)),'.')[0]),100)**

But i am getting the following error > Cannot fit unknown into the function parameter string.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Got the similar error in expression builder.

When pipeline is run by clicking on **debug**, The expression gave the correct result without any error.

**Output**:

[image]